# Different user types with different registrations

Tags: python, django

I need to create two (and later more) user types: Individuals and Companies.
When a user registers, they need to select what type they are. Depending on that, they need to fill in different forms based on each type's attributes, and later have different permissions.

What I have tried so far is extending the `AbstractUser` model to include booleans for each user type:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_individual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then I created two extra "Profile" models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='company_profile')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, help_text="Company name.")
    contact_email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
class Individual(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='individual_profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Individual, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also set up signals to automatically create the profile when a user is created:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_company_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_company:
        if created:
            Company.objects.create(user=instance)
    elif instance.is_individual:
        if created:
            Individual.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        pass

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_company_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_company:
        instance.company_profile.save()
    elif instance.is_individual:
        instance.individual_profile.save()
    else:
        pass
```

This works when I add a user via Django Admin. If I tick is_individual, the an individual is added to the Individuals table, and same for Companies.

I am struggling to find a way to allow users to do that when registering.
When they click "Register as a Company", let them fill in all the default User fields + Company fields, and save both the User and the Company instances.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading about [Django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/). Most of what you want is already built in. You don't need to create a custom user model or write much code at all.

Instead, create a group and give that group the permissions to read/create/edit/delete specific objects. Then assign a group to a user to give it that role. This can all be done in the django admin interface.

You might need to write some code that determines what the form looks like that they fill out, but that should be relatively straightforward using a template.

As another suggestions, you might consider having all users fill in their first and last name, email, etc. Even if they represent a company, you might want to have contact information for a representative of the company. The default `User` object already has these fields.

Then you can add a `company` field to your customer user object. This can be `null` if the user isn't associated with a company.